# FileTransfer Smack really slow or not working

Tags: java, android, file-transfer, smack

I am using Smack 4.1.7 on the android application and also on the server side.

I would like to transfer Files from the phone to the server so i use the following code on the phone:

```
        FileTransferNegotiator.IBB_ONLY = true;
        FileTransferManager fileTransferManager = FileTransferManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
        OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = fileTransferManager.createOutgoingFileTransfer("fulljid");
        transfer.sendFile(file);
```

and on the server side:

```
    FileTransferNegotiator.IBB_ONLY = true;
    fileTransferManager = FileTransferManager.getInstanceFor(xmppConnection);
    fileTransferManager.addFileTransferListener(new FileTransferListener() {
        public void fileTransferRequest(FileTransferRequest request) {
             IncomingFileTransfer fileTransfer = fileTransferRequest.accept();
             File file = new File("destinationpath");
             fileTransfer.receiveFile(file);
        }
    });
```

It just works if I have the line IBB_ONLY = true; in my code, but I have no idea why - can anyone tell me?

The next question is: it takes more than two minutes to upload about 200kB from the phone to the server. The same file needs not even 5 seconds to be uploaded to dropbox for example. Is this because of the IBB_ONLY or is there another issue?

Thanks for your help!

Update:
Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: did you find any specific reason for slow transfer?

Comment: No not so far. I tried everything I could imagine but couldn't fix it.

Comment: @Ajay have you found anything? I am trying to get Socks5 ByteStream working but have some problems with it - found some threads where you were discussing about them also.

Comment: yes i have tried a lot but always having issues with this , i have also check the code of spark client and tried here with android but its not working finally i moved to http file transfer.

Comment: can you please post your code here? it may be the best answer to this question